# Update UI when useRef Div Width Changes

Tags: reactjs

I have a `useRef` attached to a div. I need to update my UI when the div's width changes. I can access this using `ref.current.innerWidth`, however, when its width changes, it doesn't update other elements that depend on `ref.current.innerWidth`.

How can I do this?

CODE:

```
let ref = useRef();

return (
  <>
    <Box resizable ref={ref}>
      This is a resizable div
    </Box>

    <Box width={ref.current.innerWidth}>
      This box needs the same with as the resizable div
    </Box>
  </>
);
```

Comment: Show us your code, how did you listen to this event ?

Comment: @b3hr4d I can add the code above. But, which event are you referring to?

Comment: just add your code.

Comment: @b3hr4d added it! So, basically whenever the resizable div changes width, I want the other div's width to update too!

Comment: You should make a lifecycle using `useEffect` to lessen the data change then re-render your component based on that.

Comment: What should the `useEffect` listen for specifically? Sorry I'm really new to React... THANKS so much for your help

Answer (score 11):

You could use a ResizeObserver. Implemented like so, it will set the width everytime the size of the ref changes:

```
let ref = useRef()

const [width, setwidth] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
  const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
    setwidth(entries[0].contentRect.width)
  })
  observer.observe(ref.current)
  return () => ref.current && observer.unobserve(ref.current)
}, [])

return (
  <>
    <Box ref={ref}>
      This is a resizable div
    </Box>

    <Box width={width}>
      This box needs the same with as the resizable div
    </Box>
  </>
)
```

Comment: If you are looking at reacting to a specific element resizing (and not the entire viewport), this is the cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone looking for a reusable logic and a **Typescript** support, I created the below custom hook based on [@fredy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12367825/fredy)'s awesome [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70117032/9456688), and also fixed some issues I've found in his answer:

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";


export const useObserveElementWidth = <T extends HTMLElement>() => {
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
    const ref = useRef<T>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const observer = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
            setWidth(entries[0].contentRect.width);
        });

        if (ref.current) {
            observer.observe(ref.current);
        }

        return () => {
            ref.current && observer.unobserve(ref.current);
        };
    }, []);

    return {
        width,
        ref
    };
};
```

Then, import `useObserveElementWidth`, and use it like this:

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  const { width, ref } = useObserveElementWidth<HTMLDivElement>();

  return (
    <>
      <Box resizable ref={ref}>
        This is a resizable div
      </Box>

      <Box width={width}>
        This box needs the same with as the resizable div
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};
```

I've created an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/useobserveelementwidth-resizable-box-example-03whv2?file=/src/Box.tsx) codesandbox for it.

Answer (score 3):

You should make a lifecycle using useEffect and useState and event listener on window to listen the data change then re-render your component based on that.

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-franklin-0g6rk?file=/src/App.js)

```
  const [size, setSize] = useState(null);
  let ref = useRef();

  const updateDimensions = () => {
    console.log(ref.current.clientWidth);
    if (ref.current) setSize(ref.current.clientWidth);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateDimensions);
    setSize(ref.current.clientWidth);
    return () => {
      console.log("dismount");
      window.removeEventListener("resize", updateDimensions);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={ref}>This is a resizable div</div>

      <div
        style={{
          width: size,
          border: "1px solid"
        }}
      >
        This div needs the same with as the resizable div
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: I gave you one point. It's worthwhile to say that this solution works only when the user resizes the window, not for a generic element (eg. splitter).

Comment: thanks, but in HTML how generic elements can be resized? as I know we cant use `ref.current.addEventListener("resize",callback)`.

Comment: well, I'm using an hidden IFRAME element, as sibling of the one to be measured. That raises size changing events. Another way seems using this, although is marked as draft: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have experience with this situation. did you try to ask this in here ?